# Регулярные выражения: пробел, пайп или ничего

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть некий текст, в котором нужно захватить и распихать по группам некоторые значения. Текст:

```
тест [тест тест]
тест [[тест тест]]
тест [[тест|тест]]
тест [[тест]]
тест [тест]]ы
```

Регулярка:

```
\[{1,2}(.*?)([\s|\|]?)(.*?)\]{1,2}(\w*)
```

Всё работает, кроме знака вопроса во второй группе `([\s|\|]?)` . Без него всё отлично, с ним первая группа не захватывается. Что тут можно придумать? Учитывая, что, как видно из примеров, пробела или пайпа в тексте может не быть.

Comment: Попробуйте так https://regex101.com/r/Fjt4GI/4.

Comment: `[\[]{1,2}([^\s\|\]]{0,})[\|\s]{0,}([^\s\|\]]+){0,}[\]]{1,2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё на сасом деле просто: вместо двух последовательных опциональных шаблонов используйте один опциональный, второй - обязательный, и заключите их в опциональную незахватывающую подмаску:

```
\[{1,2}(?:(.*?)([\s|]))?(.*?)\]{1,2}(\w*)
       ^^^           ^ ^
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/jBczhk/1).

*Было* `(.*?)([\s|\|]?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: 0+ любых символов, отличных  от перевода строки, как можно меньше, и захватывающая подмаска №2: один или ноль пробельных символов или символов `|`.

*Стало* `(?:(.*?)([\s|]))?`: опциональная незахватывающая группа, которая ищет 1 или 0 повторов (т.е. как минимум один раз) 0+ любых символов, отличных  от перевода строки, как можно меньше (захватывающая подмаска №1), а затем обязательный пробельный символ  или знак `|` (захватывающая подмаска №2).